# SQL with count none zero

Tags: mysql, sql

I m trying to get count of Order Status

If count is zero then record is not shown.

**Orders** Contain: OrderID, OrderStatusID ..

**OrderStatus** Contain: OrderStatusID, OrderStatusName.

I just need a list of OrderStatus with no of orders within each Category.

sql:

```
SELECT COUNT(OrderStatusID) as TotalStatus 
FROM Orders 
GROUP BY OrderStatusID
```

If an OrderStatusID 5 has zero records then that zero count is not shown in result

results are as  3,4,5,6

Results must be 3,4,5,0,6

Comment: A SQL query can only return details on data that exists in the database. If there are no rows in table `TotalStatus` with `OrderStatusID` equal to 5, the query will not return anything. How do you know that there is `OrderStatusID` equal to 5?

Comment: Is this OrderStatusID column referring to another table's column?

Comment: If an OrderStatusId has Zero record then it shouldn't come in the result. If you have a table where all the OrderStatusId are listed, you can try joining it with Orders table to achieve desired result.

Comment: All from 1 table.

Comment: @shashankqv Could you gimme example? i do have a table where all statusID are listed. its on same table.

Comment: Edit your question and mention the table with the definitions of all the statuses.

Comment: @Webgen : can you share definitions of your table ? what do you mean by "It's on same table".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `LEFT JOIN` of `OrderStatus` to `Orders`:

```
select count(OrderID) as TotalStatus
from OrderStatus s left join Orders o
on o.OrderStatusID = s.OrderStatusID
group by s.OrderStatusID
```